# How log the client IP address with NLog in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nlog

I made a portal with ASP.NET MVC and I need to log the IP address of any client that opens this website. I added NLog with NuGet to my project and I added below tags in **Web.config**:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
  </configSections>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="default" xsi:type="File" fileName="logs/app-log.txt" archiveFileName="logs/archives/app-log.{#}.txt" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling" maxArchiveFiles="7" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" writeTo="default" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

how set my application to log any other info in addition to **IP address** of any computer that registers data with my portal? Any help will be apprecited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layout on the target configuration can be modified to add the machine name and the Client IP address

```
layout="Machine Name: ${machinename} - IP: ${aspnet-request-ip}
```

More on this you can find here https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-IP-Layout-Renderer

Edit: You may need NLog.Web for ASP.NET Web API and MVC projects.
Also note that you may get ::1 as the IP address in the localhost but it works fine when hosted.

Comment: but it only gives me the machinename not ip address

Comment: it also gives the IP address  IP: ${aspnet-request-ip}

Comment: Sorry, I checked that and it only gives me ==> (Machine Name: DESKTOP-9V3UCSU - IP: ). Do you think it is because of that I check my portal in my local computer?

Comment: make sure you have Nlog.web extension in your project

Comment: I added NLog.web as you said and I have IP: ::1 in log file. I test my app in locally and if I upload my app in host then it will log the client IP??

Comment: @Mostafa How did you solve this? I am using ASP.NET Web API and getting empty string instead of IP.

Comment: For other people out there. I solved this issue by installing NLog.Web for ASP.NET. I got ::1 as the value in the local but it worked when hosted on the server

Comment: Yes, exactly. I added NLog.web and my problem get solved.